# Soilgrids points outside of projection domain

Tags: raster, r, soilgrids, terra, homolosine

I have downloaded a global soilgrid tif from ISRIC (https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data_aggregated/5000m/ocs/) and when I import this in R with `terra::rast(filename)` (and similarly with `raster::raster(filename)`), I get the following raster:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 2902, 7962, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 5000, 5000  (x, y)
extent      : -19949750, 19860250, -6149000, 8361000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : ocs_0-30cm_mean_5000.tif 
name        : ocs_0-30cm_mean_5000
```

It seems like the min/max values of the extent are incorrect and when I attempt to aggregate and reproject the raster using a template with:

```
aggregated <- terra::project(original_raster,template_raster)
```

I get the warnings:

```
Point outside of projection domain (GDAL error 1)
PROJ: igh: Invalid latitude (GDAL error 1)
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Edit1:

This is the template raster used in the reprojection:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1044, 2160, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
extent      : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory 
name        : b1
min value   :                   -53.53975 
max value   :                    34.37675
```

Edit2:
Here is a plot of the `aggregated` raster, which actually looks fine.

[image: Aggregated Organic Carbon Stock]

Comment: They're warnings, possibly related to the `igh` projection being "interrupted", so there are points in that raster that don't have a real-world location (between the "lobes"). Do you get anything sensible when you do the aggregation? Have you tried plotting `aggregated` because warnings usually return something. Transforming interrupted projections to something "uninterrupted" is a bit hit-and-miss if it has to join the seams back up. I'd see if you can get data on another coord system or work with igh as much as possible.

Comment: The extent reported for that `SpatRaster` instance is well within the projection **co-domain**, that is not the issue. Most likely it is something with the re-projection operation. To which CRS are you trying to re-project?

Comment: `coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)`  If it's lon/lat, it's not [EPSG:4326](https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html)

Comment: There is definetly something wrong with the CRS declared for the second `SpatRaster` instance. That is the most likely cause for the error messages returned by GDAL. I suggest trying `CRS:84` instead. Another question is why would you want to "re-project" the map into a geographic CRS. Do you need to compute distances?

Comment: The second `SpatRaster` given in the edit, `template_raster`, is just a tif downloaded from Chelsa and imported with `x <- terra::rast(filename)` and then aggregated with `template_raster <- terra::aggregate(x,fact=20)`. Details of `x`:
`class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 20880, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1.tif 
name        : CHELSA_bio1_1981-2010_V.2.1`

Comment: I downloaded one of those rasters from the CHELSEA dataset. The CRS reported by `gdalinfo` presents the expected axes order: `AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],`. Apparently the software you use is not interpreting this CRS correctly.

Comment: Hmm this crs also appears in other places e.g. https://rspatial.org/raster/spatial/6-crs.html and https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/sites/default/files/2020-04/OverviewCoordinateReferenceSystems.pdf.

Comment: I've also tested this on another machine/installation of gdal (v 3.4.1)/terra (v. 1.5-21)/R (v.4.1.2), it gives the same CRS for the CHELSA dataset, but doesn't give any warnings when doing the projection.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is because the extent of your template raster is a bit off:

`-180.0001, 179.9999, -90.00014, 83.99986  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`

Now, `-180.0001` is not wrong (it is the same as `179.9999`) but I would not want to use that. And `-90.00014` is wrong, as you cannot be south of the South Pole. You could create a more consistent template like this:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(res=1/6, ymax=84)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1044, 2160, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 84  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
```